# delete all line after a specific date

Tags: bash, csv, ksh, csh

I have a lot of *.csv files. I want to delete the content after a specific line. I will delete all lines after 20031231
How do I solve this problem with some lines of a shell script?

```
Test,20031231,000107,0.74843,0.74813
Test,20031231,000107,0.74838,0.74808
Test,20031231,000108,0.74841,0.74815
Test,20031231,000108,0.74835,0.74809
Test,20031231,000110,0.74842,0.74818

Test,20040101,000100,0.73342,0.744318
```

Answer (score 2):

quick and dirty but without any other info about constraint

```
sed '1,/20031231/p;d' YourFile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a shell script, the best is to use `awk`. This will do the trick:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} {if ($2 == "20031231") print $0}' input.csv > output.csv
```

This code will write to a different file only the lines that have 20031231.

Comment: you're right to use awk, but, according OP "delete all lines after 20031231" implies equal or before threshold if any date and you're only matching one exact date.

Comment: You're right, forgot about the previous dates... Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

ignores empty lines and unmatched data

awk file:

```
$ cat awk.awk 
{
    if($2<="20031231" && $0!=""){
        print $0
    }else{
        next
    }
}
```

execution:

```
$ awk -F',' -f awk.awk input 
Test,20031231,000107,0.74843,0.74813
Test,20031231,000107,0.74838,0.74808
Test,20031231,000108,0.74841,0.74815
Test,20031231,000108,0.74835,0.74809
Test,20031231,000110,0.74842,0.74818
```

one liner:

```
$ awk -F',' '{if($2<="20031231" && $0!=""){print $0}else{next}}' input
Test,20031231,000107,0.74843,0.74813
Test,20031231,000107,0.74838,0.74808
Test,20031231,000108,0.74841,0.74815
Test,20031231,000108,0.74835,0.74809
Test,20031231,000110,0.74842,0.74818
```

Answer (score 0):

with Miller (http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/)

```
mlr --nidx --fs "," filter '$2>20031231' input
```

gives you

```
Test,20040101,000100,0.73342,0.744318
```

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` please try:

```
awk -F, '$2<=20031231' input.csv
```